# How can I clear the Android app cache?

Tags: android

I am writing a app which can programatically clear application cache of all the third party apps installed on the device. Following is the code snippet for Android 2.2

```
public static void trimCache(Context myAppctx) {

    Context context = myAppctx.createPackageContext("com.thirdparty.game", 
            Context.CONTEXT_INCLUDE_CO|Context.CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY);

    File cachDir = context.getCacheDir();        
    Log.v("Trim", "dir " + cachDir.getPath());

    if (cachDir!= null && cachDir.isDirectory()) {

        Log.v("Trim", "can read " + cachDir.canRead());
        String[] fileNames = cachDir.list();
        //Iterate for the fileName and delete
    }
}
```

My manifest has following permissions:

> android.permission.CLEAR_APP_CACHE
>   android.permission.DELETE_CACHE_FILES

Now the problem is that the name of the cache directory is printed but the list of files `cachDir.list()` always returns null. I am not able to delete the cache directory since the file list is always null.

Is there any other way to clear the application cache?

Comment: Don't you need a rooted device for this?

Answer (score 6):

> "android.permission.CLEAR_APP_CACHE" android.permission.DELETE_CACHE_FILES"

Ordinary SDK applications cannot hold the `DELETE_CACHE_FILES` permission. While you can hold `CLEAR_APP_CACHE`, there is nothing in the Android SDK that allows you to clear an app's cache.

> Is there any other way to clear the application cache?

You are welcome to clear your own cache by deleting the files in that cache.

Comment: given the correct permission, you could remove the cache folders of other apps in the external storage (only). it's not the same, but a lot of apps use those folders as the main place to put temporary files.

Comment: i want to know when ever user can click clear cache i can get notification or something else how to get??

Comment: @KOUSIKdaniel: I *think* that your process will be terminated before the cache is cleared, but I am not certain of that. I do not know of any other notification that you would get.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank You if you are getting Information kindly share it.

Comment: @CommonsWare The Exact Question is i want when ever user press and clean cache from recent apps button i can get notification

Answer (score 2):

Check out android.content.pm.PackageManager.clearApplicationUserData: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.3_r1/android/content/pm/PackageManager.java/
The other hidden methods in that class might be useful, too.

In case you've never used hidden methods before, you can access hidden methods using Java reflection.

Answer (score 1):

poate iti merge asta

```
static int clearCacheFolder(final File dir, final int numDays) {

        int deletedFiles = 0;
        if (dir!= null && dir.isDirectory()) {
            try {
                for (File child:dir.listFiles()) {

                    //first delete subdirectories recursively
                    if (child.isDirectory()) {
                        deletedFiles += clearCacheFolder(child, numDays);
                    }

                    //then delete the files and subdirectories in this dir
                    //only empty directories can be deleted, so subdirs have been done first
                    if (child.lastModified() < new Date().getTime() - numDays * DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS) {
                        if (child.delete()) {
                            deletedFiles++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                Log.e("ATTENTION!", String.format("Failed to clean the cache, error %s", e.getMessage()));
            }
        }
        return deletedFiles;
    }

    public static void clearCache(final Context context, final int numDays) {
        Log.i("ADVL", String.format("Starting cache prune, deleting files older than %d days", numDays));
        int numDeletedFiles = clearCacheFolder(context.getCacheDir(), numDays);
        Log.i("ADVL", String.format("Cache pruning completed, %d files deleted", numDeletedFiles));
    }
```

Comment: It worked. I prefer:
`long now = new Date().getTime();`
before the loop instead of declaring a new `now` instance for each file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how appropriate this is in terms of convention, but this works so far for me in my Global Application class:

```
    File[] files = cacheDir.listFiles();
    for (File file : files){
        file.delete();
    }
```

Of course, this doesn't address nested directories, which might be done with a recursive function like this (not tested extensively with subdirectories):

```
deleteFiles(cacheDir);

private void deleteFiles(File dir){
    if (dir != null){
        if (dir.listFiles() != null && dir.listFiles().length > 0){
            // RECURSIVELY DELETE FILES IN DIRECTORY
            for (File file : dir.listFiles()){
                deleteFiles(file);
            }
        } else {
            // JUST DELETE FILE
            dir.delete();
        }
    }
}
```

I didn't use `File.isDirectory` because it was unreliable in my testing.